# Using threads inside generator and yielding before the ThreadPoolExecutor has finished its tasks

Tags: python, generator, coroutine, yield, threadpoolexecutor

I was just implementing some features for our code and suddenly an idea popped in my head. Here is some code which demonstrates it:

```py
import functools
import time
import secrets
from typing import Generator, Any, Tuple
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import as_completed


def coroutine(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def start(*args, **kwargs):
        cr = func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(cr)
        return cr
    return start


def task() -> str:
    _id = str(secrets.token_hex(8))
    print(f'[INFO] starting task {_id}')
    time.sleep(5)  # hard task
    print(f'[INFO] finishing task {_id}')
    return _id


@coroutine
def gen() -> Generator[Tuple[int, str], None, None]:
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = {
            executor.submit(task): i for i in range(10)
        }
        yield
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            yield futures[future], future.result()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    g1 = gen()
    g2 = gen()
    time.sleep(6)  # doing some work while generators do their tasks inside
    for result in g1:  # and in case we need, we always can iterate through
        print(result)
    for result in g2:
        print(result)
```

The thing is - you just execute some IO blocking tasks in threads inside a generator and then just yield. While the tasks is being processed inside the generator object, you can run your own code. It resembles async/await a bit but still, they are different. So, I just wanted to ask whether this approach is cool and should it be used? Or are there some problems that I don't see? Who knows? Thank you in advance!

I want to use that approach to download multiple files from S3 bucket in background using such a method:

```py
@coroutine
def get_json_batch(self, bucket_name: str, keys: Iterable[str]
                   ) -> Generator[Tuple[str, Dict], None, None]:
    def _process(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.get_json_file_content(*args, **kwargs)
        except ClientError:
            return {}
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = {
            executor.submit(_process, bucket_name, key): key
            for key in keys
        }
        _LOG.info('Download tasks were submitted')
        yield
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            yield futures[future], future.result()
```

It seems to work, but I'm afraid there can be some problems with big. What do you think?